# Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\car-config\application\controllers\www\home.php on line 191

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

i have a problem when i'm trying to execute this code.Is just a part from my code

> Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\car-config\application\controllers\www\home.php on line 191

```
private function sendMail(){

    $objConfig = Userconfig::newObj();
    $objConfig->email = $this->arrRequest['email'];
    $objConfig->name = $this->arrRequest['name'];
    $objConfig->configuration = serialize($this->arrRequest);
    $objConfig->save();

    $strMessage = 'Configuratia a fost salvata!';

    $this->arrRequest['success'] = $strMessage;


    if(empty($this->arrRequest['name']) || empty($this->arrRequest['email']) || filter_var($this->arrRequest['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: use isset($this->arrRequest['email']) instead of using $this->arrRequest['email']

Comment: First check your object $objConfig, Its have email or not!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($this->arrRequest['email']) ||!isset($this->arrRequest['name']) || empty($this->arrRequest['name']) || empty($this->arrRequest['email']) || filter_var($this->arrRequest['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        return false;
    }

    $objConfig = Userconfig::newObj();  
    $objConfig->email =$this->arrRequest['email'];
    $objConfig->name = $this->arrRequest['name'];
    $objConfig->configuration = serialize($this->arrRequest);
    $objConfig->save();

    $strMessage = 'Configuratia a fost salvata!';

    $this->arrRequest['success'] = $strMessage;
```

or

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```